# Can a water spigot be installed on a service panel post?

Tags: water

I just installed new electrical service on my land. I have a 200 amp meter/panel & 100 amp RV panel mounted to a 6x6 post (opposite sides). This is for RV use.

I want to extend my existing water line to the Panel post and have it below and on other side of post from Service panel. Is there any code against this?
My neighbor told me the Power company said it had to be 36" away. I wonder if he was referring to front clearance, which is required per code.[image]

Comment: free standing hydrants are a thing, that way you can have some separation between the post and the water supply

Comment: @ratchetfreak-  I know they are free standing, but I want to have it supported by at least a 4x4. So, their would be a 4x4 between the hydrant and the panel post. But that's it

Answer (score 1):

No not on the opposite side there is no requirement for it to be separated.

The national electric code requires a space of 30 inches wide or the width of the equipment to be clear but I regularly put service panels adjacent to sinks or water heaters with the 30” going to the other side of the panel.

I believe this is what your neighbor may be saying and your utility wants 36” in front ok but on the other side of a post no problem.

Comment: so my main panel is on the left and my RV panel is on the right on post. If I put the water spigot on post between them, that would meet the clearance requirements? The panels  over hang to the sides of post about 4"

Comment: The faucet is attached to the side of the post but below both panels and “behind” both panels if I understand. This is similar to an RV service the space below each panel you can not put it there but on the side and below I see no problem code wise. I think this eould work a photo may be helpful I am thinking 1 post both panels are attached to.

Comment: picture added. Water would be on open side face out in pic

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking the faucet mounted on that side below the panel would be code compliant as it is not in a dedicated electrical space.

Answer (score 1):

The side of the post would probably be ok, but pay special attention to:

NEC 110.26 Space About Electrical Equipment.

> 110.26 (E)(2) Outdoor. Outdoor installations shall comply with 110.26(E)(2)(a) through (c).
>
> (c) Dedicated Equipment Space. The space equal to the width and depth
> of the equipment, and extending from grade to a height of 1.8 m (6 ft)
> above the equipment, shall be dedicated to the electrical
> installation. No piping or other equipment foreign to the electrical
> installation shall be located in this zone.

Your local jurisdictional authorities and utilities can adopt amendments and codes beyond the NEC.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I think i will be ok. Because it would not be within the footprint of either panel from grade up to the sky